# iOS code optimization

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar

I'm new in iOS development and this may be a very basic question- in my app i've 5 VC with `UITabBarController`  on each VC. I'm handling tab bar item click by-

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
{
    switch (item.tag)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            vc1 = [[VC1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC1" bundle:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:vc1.view];
            [tabbarObj setSelectedItem:[tabbarObj.items objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
            break;
        case 1:
        {
            vc2 = [[VC2 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC2" bundle:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:vc2];
        }
            break;
        case 2:
        {
            vc3 = [[VC3 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC3" bundle:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:vc3];
        }
            break;
        case 3:
        {
            [tabbarObj setSelectedItem:[tabbarObj.items objectAtIndex:3]];
        }
            break;
        case 4:
        {
            vc5 = [[VC5 alloc] initWithNibName:@"VC5" bundle:nil];
            [self.view addSubview:vc5];
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and i know this is not a right way to handle tab bar because every time when i click on a tab bat item it will add a subView on current view.
Can anybody suggest me a better way?Thanks.

Comment: allocate all of them and add as subview outside the method and use setHidden feature in the above method by taking proper references to the particular viewControllers .

Comment: one simple solution can be you create 5 view and add subview all your viewcontrollers in viewDidLoad and just hide/unhide view's as you need in above function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in Your `Appedelegate.m` file Make changes in  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` Method

```
 tabBar_Controller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *localControllersArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];



    firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];

    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
nav.tabBarItem.title = @"item1";
    nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
   [localControllersArray addObject:nav];
            [self setNav:nil];

    secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
    nav.tabBarItem.title = @"item2";
           [localControllersArray addObject:nav];

    [self setNav:nil];
 tabBar_Controller.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
   tabBar_Controller.delegate = self;
    tabBar_Controller.selectedIndex = 0;
[self.window addSubview:tabBar_Controller.view];
```

To Access Some properties after Your ViewController is Selected Use the following Code.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllers
{
    NSUInteger index=[[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewControllers];

    switch (index) {


        case 0:
        {

            NSLog(@"selected 1");

            break;
        }
        case 1:

          {
            NSLog(@"selected 2");
                    break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }


}
```

For Changing Background image of tabbar Controller you can use Following Code.

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllers{
    NSUInteger index=[[tabBarController viewControllers] indexOfObject:viewControllers];

    switch (index) {
        case 0:
            [tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act21.png"]];

            break;
        case 1:
            [tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act22.png"]];
            break;
        case 2:
            [tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_act23.png"]];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: can you please explain it?

Comment: See in my Code im Creating a navigation-controller for each view with some title (Also you can add other properties) and adding it to an Array called `LocalControllersArray`

And in the Line `tabBar_Controller.viewControllers = localControllersArray;` i m assigning all viewcontrollers to tabbar.
in `[self.window addSubview:tabBar_Controller.view];` Line i m adding the Tabbar as Subview so When you will Open the App you can See the tabbar with two View Controllers(you can Do for 5).
In delegate method You can Set Other properties Let Me Update My Answer soon.