# TabBar is not Showing in iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitabbar

I am using tabbar, my tabbar is not showing when I navigate to that controller,

here is the code of tabbar class

```
UIViewController * myTruckDept= [[NYTTruckDeparture alloc]initWithSiteName:self.siteNam andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myEditionStates = [[NYTEditionStats alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myPagingData = [[NYTPagingData alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myDownTimeLog = [[NYTDowntimeLog alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myComments = [[NYTComments alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:myTruckDept, myEditionStates, myPagingData, myDownTimeLog, myComments, nil];

self.viewControllersArray = array;
[self.view addSubview:myTruckDept.view];
self.selectedViewController = myTruckDept;
self.myTabBar.selectedItem=self.myTruckDeptTabBarItem;
```

When I push this view controller to navigation controller, tabbar is shown when navigation bar is not hidden , when I hide the navigationbar and use toolbar now tabbar at bottom is not shown.

Need a Quick reply thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

//Define UIViewControllers

```
UIViewController * myTruckDept= [[NYTTruckDeparture alloc]initWithSiteName:self.siteNam andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myEditionStates = [[NYTEditionStats alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myPagingData = [[NYTPagingData alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myDownTimeLog = [[NYTDowntimeLog alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];
UIViewController * myComments = [[NYTComments alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteName andSiteDate:self.date];
```

//Adding views in UINavigation controller

```
UINavigationController * myTruckDeptNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myTruckDept];
UINavigationController *topyummsNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myEditionStates];
UINavigationController *myEditionStatesNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myPagingData];
UINavigationController * myDownTimeLogNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myDownTimeLog];
UINavigationController * myCommentsNavC = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:myComments];
```

//Hide navigation bar

```
myTruckDeptNavC.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
topyummsNavC .navigationBar.hidden = YES;
myEditionStatesNavC.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
myDownTimeLogNavC .navigationBar.hidden = YES;
myComments NavC.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
```

//Initialize tabbar and set controllers

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: myTruckDeptNavC, topyummsNavC, myEditionStatesNavC ,myDownTimeLogNavC , myCommentsNavC, nil];
self.tabBarController.delegate = self;
```

//Presenting UITable Bar

```
[self.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:self.tabBarController animated:animated];
```

Hope this help lot.

Comment: if you still not understand please refer following step in refrence link http://goo.gl/59uta

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code For Creating `Custom tabbarController`. Here i created for two And you can make it 4 easily.

For more Understanding Check my answer :  [iOS code optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989630/ios-code-optimization/13989743#13989743)

```
tabBar_Controller = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *localControllersArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];


firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteNam andSiteDate:self.date];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
nav.tabBarItem.title = @"item1";
nav.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
nav.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
[localControllersArray addObject:nav];
[self setNav:nil];

secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithSiteName:self.siteNam andSiteDate:self.date];
nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
nav.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
nav.tabBarItem.title = @"item2";
[localControllersArray addObject:nav];
[self setNav:nil];

tabBar_Controller.viewControllers = localControllersArray;
tabBar_Controller.delegate = self;
tabBar_Controller.selectedIndex = 0;
[self.window addSubview:tabBar_Controller.view];
```